# Why has my authorship image been removed from Google SERPs

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-authorship

I recently added the relevant tags to my site and validated my email for Google Authorship. After around a week my image started showing up with results.

Today the image is no longer present and I haven't changed anything. The Structured Data Testing Tool [results](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=scotthelme.co.uk) show that it should all be working.

Have I missed something or does anyone know why it would stop displaying?

Other questions ask about situations where the image has never appeared. My image has appeared but has since stopped appearing so is a different situation.

Comment: @John Conde I feel the question is different. How do I go about having this re-opened?

Comment: By editing the question you put in into the review queue which means it will get reconsideration

Comment: I'm not sure how the answers would be any different to a question about authorship no longer showing up than they would be to a question about authorship never having shown up.  The answer on that question is "It's most likely to do with Google choosing not to display your image" and that seems likely here as well.